# How to extract/install android-ndk-r10c-linux-x86_64.bin

Tags: virtualbox, android

I downloaded Android NDK from https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html but I am not able to extract it.

If I double-click it I get an error:

> Could not display “android-ndk-r10c-linux-x86_64.bin”. The file is of an unknown type

I have selected the option in permissions to "Allow executing file as program".

When I attempt to execute it with terminal (sudo ./android-ndk-r10c-linux-x86_64.bin) I get this error:

> sudo: unable to execute ./android-ndk-r10c-linux-x86_64.bin: No such file or directory

I have 64 bit Ubuntu 14.10 running on VirtualBox. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Set up a virtual machine.  Use the .bin as a cd or disk

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/837847/how-to-install-android-ndk

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `7z x *bin` as workaround as all r10c packages are 7z archive.
To install `7z`, do `sudo apt-get install p7zip-full`.

Found that from here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78148

Answer (score 2):

Running

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
7z x android-ndk-r10c-linux-x86_64.bin
```

will extract the ndk.

Answer (score 2):

Android's NDK now ships as an self extracting executable. You likely need to set the executable bit, however:

`$ chmod +x android-ndk-r10c-linux-x86_64.bin
 $ ./android-ndk-r10c-linux-x86_64.bin`