# How to install android NDK?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk

I have downloaded Android NDK from here: `https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html`
for Linux 64-bit (x86). It is a ZIP file that i can extract easly, but where should i extract/install to get Android NDK functioning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, downloading manually NDK might be not good options for beginning.

I highly recommend you to follow these tutorial: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/index.html

If you still feel get stucked, check this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899740/android-ndk-tutorial-guide-for-beginners

Comment: While these links may answer this question theoretically, it would be better to cite the relevant parts inline in your answer in case the linked resources change or become unavailable. Generally a post cannot be considered an answer by AskUbuntu standards if it does little more than link to external resources.

Answer (score 2):

Android NDK is available as a zip file here:

https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html#stable-downloads

and after unzipping it, there are many sample program you can build within it.

In the past the way of using the NDK are documented here:

https://tthtlc.wordpress.com/2011/04/26/building-hello-gl2-sample-in-ndk-a-internal-view/

https://tthtlc.wordpress.com/2012/01/22/how-to-compile-the-android-ndk-examples-using-command-line-tools/

https://tthtlc.wordpress.com/2013/09/24/how-to-compile-android-ndk-samples-in-ubuntu-linux/

For the latest version I have extracted some samples here:

[image]

which you navigate and compile the samples yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this path:

```
/home/<usr>/Android/Sdk/
```

I extracted all my legacy NDK to that path